# Apache POI XWPFDocument object serialization

Tags: serialization, apache-poi

I'm using Apache POI methods to create and fill XWPFDocument object in my project, smth like this

```
public XWPFDocument test() {
 XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
 ...

 return doc;
}
```

but thre's a problem, for my case XWPFDocument should be serialized. 
Is there any way to serialize it?

Comment: What about `doc.write(OutputStream)` ? That's the normal way to serialise it to a file or similar

Comment: In this case method will look like 

`public OutputStream test() {
 XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
 ...
 OutputStream os = null;
 doc.write(os);
 return os;
}`
And problem still exist

Comment: What problem still exists? Well, other than the fact that you seem to be setting your stream to null before writing to it, which'll never work...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Promoting a comment to an answer...

The way to serialise a `XWPFDocument` (or in fact any POI UserModel document) is via the [write(OutputStream)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/POIXMLDocument.html#write%28java.io.OutputStream%29) method

If you need to serialise to a byte array, you'd do something like:

```
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
...

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
doc.write(baos);
return baos.toByteArray();
```

Assuming you want to serialise into something like a database or persistence framework, just get the OutputStream from that and write into it directly!

Comment: How can you set the name of the document?